# How can I replay a campaign map without loosing saves in HOMAM 6?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I want to replay the first necropolis mission with a new hero but the game warns me that doing so will erase all of my save files.

How can I replay any campaign map while still connected to the nexus without the game deleting my saves?

I still want to be able finish the campaign with my first character.

Comment: It looks as though you cannot. There is a debate about where save files are stored http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/525441-Where-are-save-files-located-Forums - But there is no definitive answer as to whether they're stored in the cloud or not. As such, I wouldn't risk it, if you don't want to lose your original character.

Comment: The warning seems to be untrue.

Started another campaign, saved in first mission, modified hero (the save warning popped up) but the old campaign saves were not deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the affinity of the campaign hero does not seem to erase any saved game files.

I tried starting a new campaign with might, saving and then restarting it with magic and my old save was not erased from the nexus.